# Which Magento version do i have?

Tags: magento-1.7, version

At the bottom of my Magento dashboard, it tells me that I have Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.

But, when I go to Magento connect, most the installed packages have version 1.9.2.2. And when I search for updates there is only 1 for addthis_sharingtool.

So what version do I have now this moment?

[image]

Comment: When you log in to your admin panel, scroll all the way to the bottom of the dashboard page. It should show you what version you have there. I believe these modules saying `1.9` are probably compatible with your `1.7` instance. Or you're running `1.9` ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would guess the version in the backend is correct but checking the code will let you know for sure.

Go to `app/Mage.php` and look for method `getVersionInfo`. If you have `1.9.2.2` it should look like below

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
{
    return array(
        'major'     => '1',
        'minor'     => '9',
        'revision'  => '2',
        'patch'     => '2',
        'stability' => '',
        'number'    => '',
    );
}
```

Comment: lol even this wont tell you correct version if someone messed up with updates. i've seen it many times people changing files. or changing CE to EE just because some EE extensions wont work , etc.

Comment: @MagenX IS THERE NOTHING WE CAN TRUST?!!1!? - but yeah... in that case it might be time to work on a new shop

Answer (score 1):

Check via Magento admin:Log into your Magento Admin Backend, Scroll to the bottom of the page in the Magento Admin Footer. The version number is listed in the center of the footer

You can also use a Chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/version-check-for-magento/aekpbnbbbgocohlbdpdfgghamedmplal

Magento version can be checked in app/Mage.php file of your Magento installation, simply search for getVersionInfo() function there:

publicstaticfunction
{
    returnarray(
        'major'=> '1',
        'minor'=> '6',
        'revision'=> '1',
        'patch'=> '0',
        'stability'=> '',
        'number'=> '',
    );
}
Some stores have the release notes and you can check at the following url: http://www.domain.com/RELEASE_NOTES.txt

Find version using SSH:

1. Login to server via SSH using root password, go to the directory where the Magento is installed and type the below command to find the Magento version installed.

cd /home/username/public_html

php -r “include ‘app/Mage.php’; echo ‘Magento version is: ‘, Mage::getVersion(); ”

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for your help.
It shows this.

return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '7',
            'revision'  => '0',
            'patch'     => '2',
            'stability' => '',
            'number'    => '',

Comment: Comment on Sander his answer, not post another answer and accept his answer if that's the one helped you. And as written you're using version 1.7.0.2.